# OnClick Javascript button to update custom fields

Tags: javascript

Below is the JS code I've used to update the `status` field on order object when clicking on custom cancel button.

The issue i am facing here is when clicking on cancel button, confirm pop up shows up asking if I want to continue with cancellation by clicking ok or cancel the process by clicking cancel on pop up.

**The status field is being updated even when i click on cancel on the pop up message.**

Here I only want to perform a field update when user clicks on ok on the pop up.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/23.0/connection.js")}

try {
var url = parent.location.href;
var updateRecords = [];
var update_Order = new sforce.SObject("Order");
update_Order.Id ="{!Order.Id}";
update_Order.Status="Cancelled";
updateRecords.push(update_Order);

result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords);
confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?');
parent.location.href = url;
} catch (e) {
alert (e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an if statement:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?')) {
    result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords);
    top.location.href = url;
}
```

The [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method returns true when the user clicks OK or presses the Enter key, and false when the user clicks cancel, the X button, or Escape.